# Wiping data on an actual phone

Tags: android

Ok, usually I use the emulator so I have just to check the "wipe-data" entry and that's it. If I'm using a phone how could I do that? Is there a way to have a "developer profile" on my phone so I don't lose my personal data?

I'm using my personal phone so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to `Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > [particular application]`, there is an option to `Clear Data`. This will delete preferences etc. for the particular application. You can delete whole applications in the usual way through the menu, or with the `adb uninstall [package name]` command.

http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=ADB